# Quarkus - No DEBUG logs appear from Java XML Digital Signature API

Tags: java, xml, cxf, quarkus, xml-dsig

I'm trying to use the Java XML Digital Signature API (https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/dig-signature-api.html) together with Quarkus 3.2.4. As stated in the Oracle article to enable debug logging you have to set the following log levels:

```
org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.level = FINER
com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.level = FINER
```

From that I assume JDK java.util.logging (JUL) is used. From the Quarkus logging documentation (https://quarkus.io/guides/logging) I understand that this should be handled by the JBoss Log Manager. No need for extra dependencies - just configure log levels in application.properties.
But when I try with the following:

```
quarkus.log.level=TRACE
quarkus.log.min-level=TRACE

quarkus.log.category."org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal".level=TRACE
quarkus.log.category."org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal".min-level=TRACE
quarkus.log.category."com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security".level=TRACE
quarkus.log.category."com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security".min-level=TRACE
```

I only get debug logs from quarkus itself and nothing from org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal or com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.

I'm using java 17.

Anyone have an idea what could be the problem?

I've made a reproducer here: https://github.com/xperjon/quarkus-xml-dsig

Comment: Have you tried passing `-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager` ?

Comment: Hi! If I set the system property on command line I get: "Could not load Logmanager "org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"
If I set it programatically with System.setProperty("java.util.logging.manager", "org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"); I still get no logs.

Comment: The CNFE is very odd...